# Why does i am getting Expression Expected ';' error

Tags: java, methods

/*getting error (Expected ';') after priyanka() method Why is this Error Occuring */

```
public class methodsPractise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        void priyanka() {
            System.out.println("so practice is good"); 
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class methodsPractise {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        priyanka();
    }
    public static void priyanka() {
        System.out.println("so practice is good"); 
    }
}
```

You can't declare method inside method.